# How to get rid of "not authorized on parse to execute command { listCollections: 1.0 }"

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my AWS EC2 instance given by my client.

On Which There Is an existing database.

But When I SSH to the server using given credentials and run the following command

> show collections

I am getting this error

> 2016-08-30T12:22:52.216+0000 E QUERY    Error: listCollections failed: {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "not authorized on parse to execute command { listCollections: 1.0 }",
>       "code" : 13

How to get my user authenticated perform such operations.Or how to get existing Admin credentials

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the security from `mongodb.conf`

```
noauth = true
#auth = true
```

so you should be able to logged in as admin now. (use `show users` to get the list of existing users in base)

Comment: How to take these changes into effect because  when I'm running 
sudo service mongodb restart   I am getting this error -> mongodb: unrecognized service

Comment: how is mongo running ? is it a service or process is started ? and who owns the process

Comment: I guess it's possess because when I run mongod 
I am getting something "like I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=30522 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit"